# How to configure mod_wsgi + apache2 to work with Flask + SocketIO?

Tags: python, flask, apache2, mod-wsgi, python-socketio

I have an application that's using Flask and Flask-SocketIO.
For now I was running it only locally but now I need to host it, in order to give access for other people.
I have VPS with apache2 and mod_wsgi.

For now it worked for me locally (I hide insignificant code):

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

but now I need to import it in to wsgi file on VPS. This is working case without socketIO:

```py
activate_this = '/var/www/mywebsite/mywebsite/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/mywebsite/mywebsite")
    
from app import app as application
```

How can I configure wsgi file to make it work with socketIO aswell?
I have tried:

```py
activate_this = '/var/www/mywebsite/mywebsite/venv/bin/activate_this.py'
with open(activate_this) as file_:
    exec(file_.read(), dict(__file__=activate_this))

import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/mywebsite/mywebsite")
    
from app import socketio as application
```

but it leaded to:

```
TypeError: 'SocketIO' object is not callable
```

which I think I understand now, why it didn't work, but still I don't know how to configure it properly, what to import as "application" in wsgi file.

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am also running into the same problem.